# Integral :$\int \tan (x)\tan (x+a) \, dx$

Tags: integration

How to integrate :

$$\int \tan (x) \tan (x+a) \, dx$$

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

Assuming $a$ as arbitrary constant i.e., independent of $x,$

use $$\tan a=\tan(x+a-x)=\frac{\tan(x+a)-\tan x}{1+\tan(x+a)\cdot \tan x}$$

$$\implies \tan(x+a)\cdot \tan x=\cot a\cdot\tan(x+a)-\cot a\cdot \tan x -1 $$

and $$\int \tan y\ dy =\ln\left|\sec y\right|+C$$

Comment: $\int\tan ydy = \ln|\sec y|+C$

Comment: @Michael, sorry for the silly mistake.Thanks for your input

Comment: Simple slip.  By the way, as an easy puzzle, what is $\ln|\sec y+\tan y|$ actually the integral of?

Comment: @Michael, $$\frac{d\ln\left|\sec y+\tan y\right|}{dy}=\frac1{(\sec y+\tan y)}\cdot (\sec y\tan y+\sec^2y)=\sec y \iff \int \sec ydy= \ln\left|\sec y+\tan y\right|+C$$

Comment: Alternatively, $$\frac1{\tan x\tan(x+a)}=\frac{\sin x\sin(x+a)}{\cos x\cos(x+a)}+1-1=\frac{\cos(x+a-x)}{\cos x\cos(x+a)}-1$$
$$=\frac{\cos a}{\sin a}\cdot\frac{\sin(x+a-x)}{\cos x\cos(x+a)}-1$$
$$=\cot a\cdot \frac{\sin(x+a)\cos x-\cos(x+a)\sin x}{\cos x\cos(x+a)}-1$$
$$=\cot a\cdot \tan(x+a)-\cot a\cdot\tan x-1$$